# Erasing the last element of a vector by looping through it

Tags: c++, vector

I want to loop through a vector and erase certain elements that correspond to a certain criteria, for example:

```
vector<int> myvector;
vector<int>::iterator it;

myvector.push_back(1);
myvector.push_back(2);
myvector.push_back(3);
myvector.push_back(4);

for(it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it){

    if((*it) == 4){
        it = myvector.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Now this works fine unless the criterion erases the last item like in the code above. How do you avoid this behaviour ?

Thanks.

EDIT------------------------------------

Now the reason I was looping through it was that there are actually 4 vectors I need to delete the element from (but the criterion is only on one vector):

In this case, is this how to go ?

```
vector<int> myvector;
vector<int> myvector2;
vector<int> myvector3;
vector<int> myvector4;
vector<int>::iterator it;
vector<int>::iterator it2;
vector<int>::iterator it3;
vector<int>::iterator it4;

myvector.push_back(1);
myvector.push_back(2);
myvector.push_back(3);
myvector.push_back(4);
```

(assume myvector2/3/4 have values inside them)

```
it2 = myvector2.begin()
it3 = myvector3.begin()
it4 = myvector4.begin()

for(it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end();){

    if((*it) == 4){
        it = myvector.erase(it);
        it2 = myvector2.erase(it2);
        it3 = myvector3.erase(it3);
        it4 = myvector4.erase(it4);
    }
    else{
    ++it;
    ++it2;
    ++it3;
    ++it4;
    }
}
```

Is there a modification to the erase/remove idiom valid in this case ?

Comment: "Now this works fine unless the criterion erases the last item."
No it doesn't.  It has undefined behavior any time you erase the
element.  (Just thought I'd mention this; other's have posted
the correct solutions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this with a for loop, there's already a well-debugged algorithm for you.

`myvector.erase(std::remove(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 4), myvector.end());`

Answer (score 5):

The usual is the remove/erase idiom, which would look something like this:

```
myvector.erase(std::remove(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 4), myvector.end());
```

Edit: Rereading your question, you mention "certain criteria". If the criteria aren't necessarily just removing a single value, you can use `std::remove_if` instead of `std::remove`, and specify your criteria in a functor.

Edit2: for the version dealing with four vectors, the *usual* method is to create a struct holding the four related values, and delete entire structs:

```
struct x4 { 
    int a, b, c, d;

    // define equality based on the key field:
    bool operator==(x4 const &other) { return a == other.a; }

    x4(int a_, int b_=0, int c_=0, ind d_=0) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_), d(d_) {}
};

std::vector<x4> myvector;

myvector.erase(std::remove(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), x4(4));
```

Again, if your criteria are more complex than you can easily express in a comparison operator, you can use `std::remove_if` instead of `std::remove`. This is also useful if/when you might need to apply different criteria at different times.

If you really *need* to keep your data in parallel vectors (e.g., you're feeding the data to something external that requires separate, contiguous arrays), then using a loop is probably as good as the alternatives.

Comment: Don't forget that if there are duplicates you need to erase from the return iterator to `end`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write the loop as :

```
for(it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); )
{
    if((*it) == 4)
        it = myvector.erase(it);
    else
        ++it; //increment here!
}
```

Because in your code, if you find `4`, you update `it` in the `if` block itself, but after that you again increment/update `it` in the `for` also which is wrong. That is why I moved it to `else` block that ensures that `it` gets incremented if you don't find `4` (or whatever value you're searching).

Also remember that `erase` returns [iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/).

Comment: @Simon:  Note that the for loop has changed.  This is because `erase` will return the next item, and `++it` isn't what you want to do when you loop in this case.

Comment: @ John & Nawaz: Thanks, now I understand that it's actually doing ++it twice and going out of bounds for the last element

Comment: Is the code I wrote in the edited portion of my question valid now?

Comment: You should avoid this construct and use the remove/erase idiom instead. Manually performing the erasures can be a O(N^2) operation in the worst case --all elements match the delete criteria, for each element all other elements are shifted one position left, for a total of N^2/2 moves. The remove/erase idiom is guaranteed to be O(N)

Comment: @Simon: There are many problems with your EDIT. First, as you've written `it = myvector.begin()` for the first vector, you've not written this for all other vectors. Second, finding `4` in first vector, doesn't mean you also find it in other vectors. Third, you increment all iterators in `else` block as if all are of same size. What if one vector has just half number of elements of the larger vector? That will reach `end` much before others, right?

Comment: @Simon: It is not really a good idea to edit the question *inline*. It will make it harder in the future to interpret why someone is proposing as an answer what is already coded in the question.

Comment: @ Nawaz: you're right about the it = myvector.begin(), it was there for all vectors, just forgot to write it..., 2nd, I just need to find the criteria in that vector and remove the corresponding elements in the other vectors, so that isn't a problem. Same thing for the vector size, I know they are all the same.

Comment: @ David: I don't quite get what you mean, is there a better way of editing the question than the way I did ?

Comment: @Simon: Then that is fine. The code should work if they're of same size. Also, if you want to erase the corresponding elements from other vectors, then none of the solution is correct except mine :D

Answer (score 0):

`erase` is generally used with `remove` (Also have a look at [erase-remove](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove) idiom) as shown below

```
myvector.erase(std::remove(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 4), myvector.end());
```

Comment: Prasoon: You're confusing `erase` with `remove`. It's `remove` which doesn't delete the element actually!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(it = myvector.begin(); it < myvector.end(); ++it){

    if((*it) == 4){
        it = myvector.erase(it);
    }
}
```

This will make sure your loop will break if the `it >= myvector.end()`.

Comment: If there is any issue using this kind of loop, please help me understanding the concept better.